# How to return my response in json in the controller. (Asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, typeahead.js

I use toastr for the notifications of my form. I always receive the error message and yet the data is saved in the database. I think that the error comes from the controller because I do not send back in json. Thanks for your help.

-----Controlleur : ---------------

```
        public ActionResult CreateNewRentals(NewRentalDto newRental)
    {
        var hour = DateTime.Now;
        var customer = _context.Customers.Single(
            c => c.Id == newRental.CustomerId);

        var movies = _context.Movie.Where(
            c => newRental.MovieId.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();

        foreach (var movie in movies)
        {
            if (movie.NumberAvailable == 0)
               return BadRequest("le film est introuvable");

            movie.NumberAvailable--;
            var rental = new Rental
            {

                Customer = customer,
                Movie = movie,
                DateRented = DateTime.Now
            };

            _context.Rentals.Add(rental);

        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```

----------------La view --------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">




    $(document).ready(function () {

        var vm = {
            movieId: []
        };
        var customers = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: customers,
            remote: {
                url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#customer').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            name: 'customers',
            display: 'name',

            source: customers
        }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, customer) {
            vm.customerId = customer.id;



        });

        /* MOVIES */

        var movies = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/api/movies?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });
        $('#movie').typeahead({

            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            name: 'movies',
            display: 'name',
            source: movies
        }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, movie) {
            $("#movies").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + movie.name + "</li>");
            $("#movie").typeahead("val", "");
            vm.movieId.push(movie.id);
        });
        $("#newRental").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/newRentals",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(vm),
                success: function (data) {
                    toastr.success(' successfully!');

                },
                error: function () {
                    toastr.error( 'error!');
                }
            });

        });
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Just remove `dataType: "json"` then the  client is not expecting JSON back in the response. Either that, or return some JSON from the server, if there is anything useful you could return

Comment: P.S. _"I always receive the error message"_ ...what exactly is the error message and where do you see it? If you know it, tell us. Then we don't have guess the real cause based on your speculations.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing nothing to the Ok() result. Either pass a value like so: return Ok(OBJECT HERE) or return new JsonResult(OBJECT HERE). Difference being that Ok() returns HTTP status 200.